# Install Twilio onto EC2 RHEL instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, twilio

I was wondering how I install Twilio onto my RHEL EC2 instance. I have already tried, and this is what happened:[image: Error 1]

Naturally, I decided to search for the package instead. This time, I realized that I could not find anything named Twilio:[image: Error 2]

How should I go about installing Twilio onto my EC2 instance? Thanks in advance for all the help.

Jack

Comment: Twilio isn't a server that you install.  Its a cloud service that you can make HTTP requests to from an application that you create.  If you want to build that app using Node and run it on your EC2 instance you can use NPM to install the Twilio helper library and use that in your Node app.  https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/node

Comment: @DevinRader That makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twilio is a communications service. You do not install it.

If you are developing applications that use Twilio, then you would install the application and the Twilio SDK for the language that you are using.

Here is a link to the Twilio Libraries (SDKs):

[Server-Side SDKs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries)

If you are looking to install the Twilio Client for VOIP:

[THE TWILIO.JS LIBRARY: TWILIO IN THE BROWSER](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/twilio-js)